# video thumbnail on Android 2.1 (API level 7)

Tags: android, video, media, thumbnails

Is it possible to get a thumbnail from video file specified by a file path/name and stored in a custom folder on Android 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this...

```
private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
            Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            return thumb;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think this will work with any file stored in a custom folder. Am I wrong here?

Comment: what is ID in this context? i am also looking to do this with a full path.

Comment: here Id is the ID of the image of which you want thumbnail.